# Getting count of values in dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am having a dictionary type `<int, list<int>>`. I am trying to count number of value instances repeated for that particular key.

I tried

```
LINQquery = dict.SelectMany(keyvalues => keyvalues.Value.GroupBy(values => values).Select(values => new {key = keyvalues.Key, value = values.Key, count = values.Count(),votescasted = keyvalues.Value.Count}));
resultList = LINQquery.ToList();
```

By this LINQ I am creating a new list entry for every unique value in my dictionary. I am ending up with multiple key entries in my list. How can I modify my query so that I will have a result list having key,countvalue1,countofvalue2..,countofvalueN ?

my input is dict{500,{25,26,25,25}}
with my LINQ I am getting a list 
key=500,value=25,count=3
key=500,value=26,count=1

how can I modify my query so that my output list can be 
key=500,countof25=3,countof26=1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing sample input and expected output. It'll make it a lot easier to help you than a *description* of what you're doing.

Comment: sorry for the typo.. dictionary type is int,list{int}

Comment: input dictionary{500,{25,26,25,25} output list key = 500,countof25= 3, countof26=1

Comment: No, don't add comments. Edit your question, putting in sufficient time to make it a really high quality question. Write real code rather than pseudo-code. Pay attention to the formatting. Basically, read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
var x = dict
    .Select(d => new { Key = d.Key, 
                       Counts = d.Value.GroupBy(v => v)
                                        .Select(g => 
                                             new { Value = g.Key, 
                                                   Count = g.Count() })});
```

then we can add:

```
x.Select(i => $"Key = {i.Key}, " + 
  String.Join(", ", i.Counts.Select(c => $"countof{c.Value}={c.Count}" ))).Dump();
```

and we get :

```
Key = 500, countof25=3, countof26=1
```